# Only 10 Sahabas were given the news of Paradise, what about the others?

Tags: hadith, jannah, sahaba

There were many of Sahabas (Peace & Blessing upon all of them), some says 200 000, some other says 124 000 witnessed the farewell. Thousands of Sahabas RA died in battles. Out of all these Sahabas, only 10 were given the news of Janna.

> The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Abu Bakr will be in Paradise, ‘Umar will be in Paradise, ‘Uthmaan will be in Paradise, ‘Ali will be in Paradise, Talhah will be in Paradise, al-Zubayr will be in Paradise, ‘Abd al-Rahmaan ibn ‘Awf will be in Paradise, Sa’d will be in Paradise, Sa’eed will be in Paradise, and Abu ‘Ubaydah ibn al-Jarraah will be in Paradise.” (Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 3680). Sa’d is Sa’d ibn Abi Waqqaas, and Sa’eed is Sa’eed ibn Zayd.

My question:

1. What about other Sahaba RA ?
2. Is there any Quranic Verse or Hadith related to them about their
   judgements ?

NB: In no way I am contesting the fact that Sahaba RA will not enter Janna, it is a question which I asked myself and for which I don't have the answers

Jazak Allah

Comment: It is a good question, could you add the hadith to your question with references also?

Comment: 'There are also a number of other Sahaabah who were given the glad tidings of Paradise, such as Khadeejah bint Khuwaylid, ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Salaam, ‘Ukaashah ibn Muhsan and others, but the ten mentioned above are called the ten who were given the glad tidings of Paradise because their glad tidings came in one hadith.' https://islamqa.info/en/5852

Comment: I think my answer on https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/why-bilal-r-a-name-was-not-included-in-the-names-of-ten-sahabas-to-enter-paradis/45579#45579 can be considered as an answer of your question.

Answer (score -3):

There is no specific name for who will enter Janna, At least as far as I know. this words arrived after the Battle of Badr, for the SAHABAS who fought in the battle:

> [Quran 33:23](https://quran.com/33/23) Among the believers are men true to what they
>   promised Allah . Among them is he who has fulfilled his vow [to the
>   death], and among them is he who awaits [his chance]. And they did not
>   alter [the terms of their commitment] by any alteration
>
> [Quran 33:24](https://quran.com/33/24) That Allah may reward the truthful for their truth
>   and punish the hypocrites if He wills or accept their repentance.
>   Indeed, Allah is ever Forgiving and Merciful.

Comment: as far as specific names are concerned, there is bro, have a look at the question edits