# How many sahaba's are declared that they are going to heaven when they alive

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sahaba

I heard few sahaba's they got the ticket to heaven when they are in the earth: like **Umar R.A** and **Abubakar**

1. How many else got there?
2. Who are the favorite sahabas of the Prophet?

Comment: These are two distinct questions and should be asked seperatly (see [in Meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)), as for the first question the answer is many some of them are quoted in [Why Bilal was not included in the names of the ten sahabas to enter jannah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/why-bilal-r-a-name-was-not-included-in-the-names-of-ten-sahabas-to-enter-paradis/45579#45579)

Comment: The second question seems to me rather opinion-based!

Comment: @Reader All the mentioned answers below represent (mostly) illogical and hence weak hadiths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither the number of companions of the Prophet ﷺ who were told of their place in Paradise while they were still alive is known, nor are all their names. In addition to the well-known hadith about the ten companions who were given the good tidings of being in Paradise:

> حَدَّثَنَا هِشَامُ بْنُ عَمَّارٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عِيسَى بْنُ يُونُسَ، حَدَّثَنَا صَدَقَةُ بْنُ الْمُثَنَّى أَبُو الْمُثَنَّى النَّخَعِيُّ، عَنْ جَدِّهِ، رِيَاحِ بْنِ الْحَارِثِ سَمِعَ جَدَّهُ، سَعِيدَ بْنَ زَيْدِ بْنِ عَمْرِو بْنِ نُفَيْلٍ يَقُولُ كَانَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ عَاشِرَ عَشَرَةٍ فَقَالَ: أَبُو بَكْرٍ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعُمَرُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعُثْمَانُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعَلِيٌّ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَطَلْحَةُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَالزُّبَيْرُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَسَعْدٌ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ فِي الْجَنَّةِ.‏ فَقِيلَ لَهُ مَنِ التَّاسِعُ قَالَ أَنَا.‏
>
> It was narrated that Sa'eed bin Zaid bin 'Amr bin Nufail said: "The Messenger of Allah was one of the Ten (given glad tidings of Paradise). He said: 'Abu Bakr will be in Paradise; 'Umar will be in Paradise; 'Uthman will be in Paradise; 'Ali will be in Paradise; Talhah will be in Paradise; Zubair will be in Paradise; Sa'd will be in Paradise; 'Abdur-Rahman will be in Paradise." He was asked: 'Who will be the ninth?' He said: 'I will.'"
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Ibn Majah, Vol. 1, Book 1, Hadith 133](https://sunnah.com/urn/1301370)</sub>

> حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْعَزِيزِ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ حُمَيْدٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ عَوْفٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم: أَبُو بَكْرٍ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعُمَرُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعُثْمَانُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعَلِيٌّ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَطَلْحَةُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَالزُّبَيْرُ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَعَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ عَوْفٍ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَسَعْدٌ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَسَعِيدٌ فِي الْجَنَّةِ وَأَبُو عُبَيْدَةَ بْنُ الْجَرَّاحِ فِي الْجَنَّةِ.‏
>
> Narrated 'Abdur-Rahman bin 'Awf: that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Abu Bakr is in Paradise, 'Umar is in Paradise, 'Uthman is in Paradise, 'Ali is in Paradise, Talhah is in Paradise, Az-Zubair is in Paradise, 'Abdur-Rahman bin 'Awf is in Paradise, Sa'd bin Abi Waqqas is in Paradise, Sa'eed is in Paradise, and Abu 'Ubaidah bin Al-Jarrah is in Paradise."
>
> <sub>— [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Vol. 1, Book 46, Hadith 3747](https://sunnah.com/urn/736260)</sub>

There are verses in the Qur'an and other hadiths that give tidings to others, some of which were mentioned by name. The list (not conclusive) is below:

- Khadīja bint Khuwailid (the Prophet's wife):

  > حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ نُمَيْرٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبِي وَمُحَمَّدُ بْنُ بِشْرٍ الْعَبْدِيُّ، عَنْ إِسْمَاعِيلَ، قَالَ قُلْتُ لِعَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ أَبِي أَوْفَى أَكَانَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم بَشَّرَ خَدِيجَةَ بِبَيْتٍ فِي الْجَنَّةِ قَالَ نَعَمْ بَشَّرَهَا بِبَيْتٍ فِي الْجَنَّةِ مِنْ قَصَبٍ لاَ صَخَبَ فِيهِ وَلاَ نَصَبَ.‏
  >
  > Ismail reported: I said to 'Abdullah b. Abi Aufa: Did Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) give glad tidings of Paradise to Khadija? He said: Yes. He did give glad tidings to her of a palace of jewels in Paradise wherein there would be no noise and no toil.
  >
  > <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 44, Hadith 104](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/104)</sub>
- Fātima bint Mohammad (the Prophet's daughter):

  > حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو نُعَيْمٍ، حَدَّثَنَا زَكَرِيَّاءُ، عَنْ فِرَاسٍ، عَنْ عَامِرٍ، عَنْ مَسْرُوقٍ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ ـ رضى الله عنها ـ قَالَتْ أَقْبَلَتْ فَاطِمَةُ تَمْشِي، كَأَنَّ مِشْيَتَهَا مَشْىُ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم: مَرْحَبًا بِابْنَتِي.‏ ثُمَّ أَجْلَسَهَا عَنْ يَمِينِهِ أَوْ عَنْ شِمَالِهِ، ثُمَّ أَسَرَّ إِلَيْهَا حَدِيثًا، فَبَكَتْ فَقُلْتُ لَهَا لِمَ تَبْكِينَ ثُمَّ أَسَرَّ إِلَيْهَا حَدِيثًا فَضَحِكَتْ فَقُلْتُ مَا رَأَيْتُ كَالْيَوْمِ فَرَحًا أَقْرَبَ مِنْ حُزْنٍ، فَسَأَلْتُهَا عَمَّا قَالَ‏.‏ فَقَالَتْ مَا كُنْتُ لأُفْشِيَ سِرَّ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم حَتَّى قُبِضَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَسَأَلْتُهَا فَقَالَتْ أَسَرَّ إِلَىَّ: إِنَّ جِبْرِيلَ كَانَ يُعَارِضُنِي الْقُرْآنَ كُلَّ سَنَةٍ مَرَّةً، وَإِنَّهُ عَارَضَنِي الْعَامَ مَرَّتَيْنِ، وَلاَ أُرَاهُ إِلاَّ حَضَرَ أَجَلِي، وَإِنَّكِ أَوَّلُ أَهْلِ بَيْتِي لَحَاقًا بِي.‏ فَبَكَيْتُ فَقَالَ: أَمَا تَرْضَيْنَ أَنْ تَكُونِي سَيِّدَةَ نِسَاءِ أَهْلِ الْجَنَّةِ ـ أَوْ نِسَاءِ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ.‏ فَضَحِكْتُ لِذَلِكَ‏.‏
  >
  > Narrated 'Aisha: Once Fatima came walking and her gait resembled the gait of the Prophet (ﷺ) . The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Welcome, O my daughter!" Then he made her sit on his right or on his left side, and then he told her a secret and she started weeping. I asked her, "Why are you weeping?" He again told her a secret and she started laughing. I said, "I never saw happiness so near to sadness as I saw today." I asked her what the Prophet (ﷺ) had told her. She said, "I would never disclose the secret of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)." When the Prophet (ﷺ) died, I asked her about it. She replied. "The Prophet (ﷺ) said: 'Every year Gabriel used to revise the Qur'an with me once only, but this year he has done so twice. I think this portends my death, and you will be the first of my family to follow me.' So I started weeping. Then he said. 'Don't you like to be the chief of all the ladies of Paradise or the chief of the believing women? So I laughed for that."
  >
  > <sub>— [Sahih al-Bukhari, Book 61, Hadith 129](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/129)</sub>
- Al-Ḥassan and Al-Ḥussayn (the Prophet's grandsons):

  > حَدَّثَنَا مَحْمُودُ بْنُ غَيْلاَنَ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو دَاوُدَ الْحَفَرِيُّ، عَنْ سُفْيَانَ، عَنْ يَزِيدَ بْنِ أَبِي زِيَادٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ أَبِي نُعْمٍ، عَنْ أَبِي سَعِيدٍ الْخُدْرِيِّ، رضى الله عنه قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم: الْحَسَنُ وَالْحُسَيْنُ سَيِّدَا شَبَابِ أَهْلِ الْجَنَّةِ.‏
  >
  > Narrated Abu Sa'eed: that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Al-Hasan and Al-Husain are the chiefs of the youth of Paradise."
  >
  > <sub>— [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Vol. 1, Book 46, Hadith 3768](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/49/167)</sub>
- 'Ā'isha bint Abi Bakr (the Prophet's wife):

  > أَخْبَرَنَا الشَّيْخُ أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ إِسْحَاقَ، أَنْبَأَ مُوسَى بْنُ إِسْحَاقَ الْقَاضِي، ثنا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، وَمُحَمَّدُ بْنُ بَكَّارٍ، قَالَا: ثنا يُوسُفُ بْنُ يَعْقُوبَ الْمَاجِشُونِ، حَدَّثَنِي أَبِي، عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ كَعْبِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، رَضِيَ اللَّهُ عَنْهَا، قَالَتْ: قُلْتُ: يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ مَنْ مِنْ أَزْوَاجِكَ فِي الْجَنَّةِ؟ قَالَ: أَمَا إِنَّكِ مِنْهُنَّ. قَالَتْ: فَخُيِّلَ لِي أَنَّ ذَاكَ أَنَّهُ لَمْ يَتَزَوَّجْ بِكْرًا غَيْرِي
  >
  > <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
  >
  > Narrated 'Ā'isha: "I asked: 'O Messenger of Allah, who among your wives will be in *Jannah*?' He said:'But you are one of them.' It occurred to me at the time that he had not married a virgin other than me."
  >
  > <sub>— [Al-Mustadrak 'Ala aṣ-Ṣaḥīḥayn, Vol. 5, pp. 14, Hadith 6743](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/7456#p1)</sub>
- Zainab bint Jahsh (the Prophet's wife) and the rest of his wives:

  > حَدَّثَنَا مَحْمُودُ بْنُ غَيْلاَنَ أَبُو أَحْمَدَ، حَدَّثَنَا الْفَضْلُ بْنُ مُوسَى السِّيْنَانِيُّ، أَخْبَرَنَا طَلْحَةُ بْنُ يَحْيَى بْنِ طَلْحَةَ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ بِنْتِ طَلْحَةَ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ أُمِّ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ، قَالَتْ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم: أَسْرَعُكُنَّ لَحَاقًا بِي أَطْوَلُكُنَّ يَدًا.‏ قَالَتْ فَكُنَّ يَتَطَاوَلْنَ أَيَّتُهُنَّ أَطْوَلُ يَدًا.‏ قَالَتْ فَكَانَتْ أَطْوَلَنَا يَدًا زَيْنَبُ لأَنَّهَا كَانَتْ تَعْمَلُ بِيَدِهَا وَتَصَدَّقُ.‏
  >
  > 'A'isha, the Mother of the Faithful, reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: One who has the longest hands amongst you would meet me most immediately. She farther said: They (the wives of Allah's Apostle) used to measure the hands as to whose hand was the longest and it was the hand of Zainab that was the longest amongst them, as she used to work with her hand and Spend (that income) on charity.
  >
  > <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 44, Hadith 146](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/146)</sub>
- Bilāl ibn Rabāḥ:

  > حَدَّثَنَا عُبَيْدُ بْنُ يَعِيشَ، وَمُحَمَّدُ بْنُ الْعَلاَءِ الْهَمْدَانِيُّ، قَالاَ حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو أُسَامَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي حَيَّانَ، وَحَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ نُمَيْرٍ، - وَاللَّفْظُ لَهُ - حَدَّثَنَا أَبِي، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو حَيَّانَ التَّيْمِيُّ يَحْيَى بْنُ سَعِيدٍ عَنْ أَبِي زُرْعَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم لِبِلاَلٍ عِنْدَ صَلاَةِ الْغَدَاةِ: يَا بِلاَلُ حَدِّثْنِي بِأَرْجَى عَمَلٍ عَمِلْتَهُ عِنْدَكَ فِي الإِسْلاَمِ مَنْفَعَةً فَإِنِّي سَمِعْتُ اللَّيْلَةَ خَشْفَ نَعْلَيْكَ بَيْنَ يَدَىَّ فِي الْجَنَّةِ.‏ قَالَ بِلاَلٌ مَا عَمِلْتُ عَمَلاً فِي الإِسْلاَمِ أَرْجَى عِنْدِي مَنْفَعَةً مِنْ أَنِّي لاَ أَتَطَهَّرُ طُهُورًا تَامًّا فِي سَاعَةٍ مِنْ لَيْلٍ وَلاَ نَهَارٍ إِلاَّ صَلَّيْتُ بِذَلِكَ الطُّهُورِ مَا كَتَبَ اللَّهُ لِي أَنْ أُصَلِّيَ.‏
  >
  > Abu Huraira reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said to Bilal: Bilal, narrate to me which act at the time of morning prayer you did in Islam for which you hope to receive good reward, for I heard during the night the sound of your steps before me in Paradise. Bilal said: I did not do any act in Islam for which I hope to get any benefit but this that when I perform complete ablution during the night or day I observe prayer with that purification what Allah has ordained for me to pray.
  >
  > <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 44, Hadith 154](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/154)</sub>
- 'Ukkasha ibn Miḥṣan:

  > حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ خَلَفٍ الْبَاهِلِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا الْمُعْتَمِرُ، عَنْ هِشَامِ بْنِ حَسَّانَ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدٍ، - يَعْنِي ابْنَ سِيرِينَ - قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي عِمْرَانُ، قَالَ قَالَ نَبِيُّ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم: يَدْخُلُ الْجَنَّةَ مِنْ أُمَّتِي سَبْعُونَ أَلْفًا بِغَيْرِ حِسَابٍ.‏ قَالُوا وَمَنْ هُمْ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ قَالَ: هُمُ الَّذِينَ لاَ يَكْتَوُونَ وَلاَ يَسْتَرْقُونَ وَعَلَى رَبِّهِمْ يَتَوَكَّلُونَ.‏ فَقَامَ عُكَّاشَةُ فَقَالَ ادْعُ اللَّهَ أَنْ يَجْعَلَنِي مِنْهُمْ.‏ قَالَ: أَنْتَ مِنْهُمْ.‏ قَالَ فَقَامَ رَجُلٌ فَقَالَ يَا نَبِيَّ اللَّهِ ادْعُ اللَّهَ أَنْ يَجْعَلَنِي مِنْهُمْ.‏ قَالَ: سَبَقَكَ بِهَا عُكَّاشَةُ.‏
  >
  > It is reported on the authority of 'Imran that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: Seventy thousand people of my Ummah would be admitted into Paradise without rendering any account. They (the companions) said: Who would be of those (fortunate persons)? He (the Holy Prophet) said: Those who do not cauterise and practice charm, but repose trust in their Lord, 'Ukkasha then stood up and said: Supplicate (before) Allah that He should make me one among them. He (the Holy Prophet) said: Thou art one among them He (the narrator) said: A man stood up and said: Apostle of Allah, supplicate (before) Allah that He should make me one among them. He (the Prophet said: 'Ukkasha has preceded you (in this matter).
  >
  > <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 1, Hadith 432](https://sunnah.com/muslim:218a)</sub>
- The family of Yāssir:

  > حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو الْعَبَّاسِ مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ يَعْقُوبَ، ثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الْجَبَّارِ، ثَنَا يُونُسُ بْنُ بُكَيْرٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ إِسْحَاقَ قَالَ: كَانَ عَمَّارُ بْنُ يَاسِرٍ وَأَبُوهُ وَأُمُّهُ أَهْلَ بَيْتِ إِسْلَامٍ، وَكَانَ بَنُو مَخْزُومٍ يُعَذِّبُونَهُمْ، فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ: صَبْرًا يَا آلَ يَاسِرٍ، فَإِنَّ مَوْعِدَكُمُ الْجَنَّةُ
  >
  > <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
  >
  > Narrated Ibn Is'ḥāq: 'Ammār ibn Yāssir and his father and his mother were a house of Islam. Banu Makhzūm used to torture them. The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said: "Patience *Āl Yāssir*, for your promised place [of meeting with the Prophet ﷺ] is Paradise.
  >
  > <sub>— [Al-Mustadrak 'Ala aṣ-Ṣaḥīḥayn, Vol. 4, pp. 432, Hadith 5646](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/6089#p1)</sub>
- Ahl al-Bay'ah (the companions that witnesses [the treaty of Ḥudaybiyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Hudaybiyyah)):

  > حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ، حَدَّثَنَا اللَّيْثُ، عَنْ أَبِي الزُّبَيْرِ، عَنْ جَابِرٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم: لاَ يَدْخُلُ النَّارَ أَحَدٌ مِمَّنْ بَايَعَ تَحْتَ الشَّجَرَةِ.‏ قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى هَذَا حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ صَحِيحٌ.‏
  >
  > Narrated Jabir: that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "None of those who gave the pledge under the tree shall enter the Fire."
  >
  > <sub>— [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Vol. 1, Book 46, Hadith 3860](https://sunnah.com/urn/737470)</sub>

  > لَّقَدْ رَضِيَ اللَّهُ عَنِ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ إِذْ يُبَايِعُونَكَ تَحْتَ الشَّجَرَةِ فَعَلِمَ مَا فِي قُلُوبِهِمْ فَأَنزَلَ السَّكِينَةَ عَلَيْهِمْ وَأَثَابَهُمْ فَتْحًا قَرِيبًا
  >
  > Certainly was Allah pleased with the believers when they pledged allegiance to you, [O Muhammad], under the tree, and He knew what was in their hearts, so He sent down tranquillity upon them and rewarded them with an imminent conquest
  >
  > <sub>— [Surah Al-Fath [48:18]](https://quran.com/48/18/)</sub>

The favorite companions of the Prophet ﷺ were the subject of a hadith that listed only two men by names:

1. Abu Bakr aṣ-Ṣiddīq
2. 'Umar ibn al-Khattāb.

When the Prophet ﷺ appointed ['Amr bn al'Āṣ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27Amr_ibn_al-%27As) to head the Muslims' army in [Dhāt as-Salāsil Expedition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_of_Amr_ibn_al-As) right after he embraced Islam (which was in 8 A.H.), 'Amr assumed that this was because the Prophet ﷺ favored him over other companions, so he asked them that question:

> أَخْبَرَنِي عَمْرُو بْنُ الْعَاصِ، أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم بَعَثَهُ عَلَى جَيْشِ ذَاتِ السَّلاَسِلِ فَأَتَيْتُهُ فَقُلْتُ أَىُّ النَّاسِ أَحَبُّ إِلَيْكَ؟ قَالَ: عَائِشَةُ‏.‏ قُلْتُ: مِنَ الرِّجَالِ؟ قَالَ: أَبُوهَا.‏ قُلْتُ ثُمَّ مَنْ؟ قَالَ: عُمَرُ.‏ فَعَدَّ رِجَالاً.
>
> 'Amr ibn al-'As reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) sent him in command of the army dispatched to Dhat-as-Salasil. When 'Amr ibn al-'As came back to the Prophet (ﷺ) he said: Who amongst people are dearest to you? He said: A'isha. He then said: Who amongst men? He said: Her father, and I said: And who next? He said: Umar. He then enumerated some other men.
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 44, Hadith 9](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/9)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There are 10 Sahabas whom the prophet said they will be in paradise

The prophet said:

> *Abu Bakr will be in Paradise, ‘Umar will be in Paradise, ‘Uthmaan will be in Paradise, ‘Ali will be in Paradise, Talhah will be in Paradise, al-Zubayr ibn al Awwam will be in Paradise, ‘Abd al-Rahmaan ibn ‘Awf will be in Paradise, Sa’d ibn abi Waqas will be in Paradise, Sa’eed ibn Zayd will be in Paradise, and Abu ‘Ubaydah ibn al-Jarraah will be in Paradise.”*

Al-Tirmidhi, 3680.

About the favourite sahaba, the prophet did not state clearly that he favours one of them. However he favoured different sahabas at different times for example:

He favored Abu Bakar multiple times, so did Uthman, Bilal, Ali, Saad bin Abi Waqas, and many more.

He called Khalid Bin Waleed “Sword of Allah”.

He allowed only two companions inside the Kaaba with him, Bilal and Osama.

He gave military leadership role to different people at different time.

He gave the military commander of the largest army of Muslims to fight the Romans to Osama bin Zaid (17 years old).

Answer (score 2):

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "**Abu Bakr** is in Paradise, **'Umar** is in Paradise, **'Uthman** is in Paradise, **'Ali** is in Paradise, **Talhah** is in Paradise, **Az-Zubair** is in Paradise, **'Abdur-Rahman** **bin 'Awf** is in Paradise, **Sa'd bin Abi Waqqas** is in Paradise, **Sa'eed** is in Paradise, and **Abu 'Ubaidah bin Al-Jarrah** is in Paradise." ([Jami' Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/636260))

These are ten people who were given the glad tidings of Paradise together (in one hadith), but there are many more people who were told they would be in Paradise in different one-of incidents, so it would not be easy to compile all of them.

As for whom the Prophet (SAW) loved the most:

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) sent Amr bin Al As as the commander of the troops of Dhat-us-Salasil. Amr bin Al- As said, "(On my return) I came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and said, '**Which people do you love most?**' He replied, **Aisha**.' I said, 'From amongst the men?' He replied, '**Her father (Abu Bakr)**'. I said, 'Whom (do you love) next?' He replied, "Umar.' Then he counted the names of many men, and I became silent for fear that he might regard me as the last of them." ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/384))

The Prophet (SAW) loved Aisha (RA) the most, and Abu Bakr (RA) from the male Sahaba.

Comment: And how to deal with this? [Contradictory hadiths on the most beloved individuals to the holy prophet ..](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32888/contradictory-hadiths-on-the-most-beloved-individuals-to-the-holy-prophet-in-jam)

Comment: @Medi1Saif . None of the (sahih or hasan) hadith contradict the statement that Abu Bakr (RA) was the most loved by the Prophet (SAW).